# How to use JavaCv's cvSaveImage in android

Tags: java, android, javacv

I have created an app using javaCv and 
I'm trying to save an image in android using

```
cvSaveImage("/storage/sdcard0/watermarked/test.jpg", yCrCb);
cvSaveImage("/storage/extSdCard/test.jpg",yCrCb);
```

where yCrCb is an IplImage.

There is no exception error and the program runs smoothly but the files are not saved into the path as mentioned above.
I would like to ask what might be the possible problems ? is it the naming convention of the file name ?

If it helps, I have a java application counterpart of this app and the java version works fine when i use the line

```
cvSaveImage("C:\\testing123.jpg", yCrCb);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hi I have used same thing for storing the image.

For getting the path to sdcard, I have used the Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();

append the folder name to this path where you want to store the image

try this and also make sure that you have written permission in the xml file.

Comment: Hi, 
I have tried this but it still doesn't work

 `String filename;
  filename =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/test.jpg";
  cvSaveImage(filename, yCrCb);`

Permission wise , all i have to do is add the Uses permission for `android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>`  right ?

Comment: For some weird reason it works perfectly fine right after i pull out the usb cable and reinsert it into my pc. Thanks alot Jack !

Comment: You have written correct permission in xml file. I had faced a similar problem. Initially the folder was not getting created in the sdcard. once I created it manually and it worked.So then I had to write separate code to create that folder when the app is installed first time. You might try it as well.hope it works